Changing working directory in parent process
I never faced this before, and I can't find any general reference: is it allowed possible to change the parent process working directory (say from C code) and how?
Think of it as a general question, possibly with a portable solution (Windows, Linux). I'm thinking of a command line application, that on exit just leaves my prompt on a different path.
[EDIT]
My question need to be changed, as what I was asking for isn't possible then.
I just wanted to share the solution taken in an application, that has the resulting effect of what I was asking - though without what I wrongly implied to be viable.
In the very nice file lister lf has been employed a possible solution. The application can be run from a shell script/batch file (see sources, etc/lfcd.cmd), then it can return the new path as text, and the script do a cd to this new path.
As it is a solution similar to what I thought, and it already works for a fine software, I think it deserves to be mentioned.

Changing the working directory of an unrelated, or even parent process, could lead to quite severe problems and security implications.

It isn't clear what you mean by "calling process". Processes don't really call each other like say functions do. A process can create another process but then the two are not in any special relationship, except the parent can wait for the child to terminate.

@n Read "calling" as "parent", fixed

So you go to the bathroom to do some, you know, live streaming, and in the middle of the process your son forcefully and instantly transports you to the living room because he wants to play a new videogame with you. I imagine you would be rather upset there and then... It looks like you have an XY problem in hand.

@LuC are you wondering how the cd command changes the shell's current directory? There is no cd command line application, it's a command built into the shell.

@Jabberwocky: on macOS, there is an executable /usr/bin/cd.  Using it seldom does anything useful — it certainly doesn't change the parent process's directory.  It does allow you to detect whether you can do a shell built-in cd or use chdir() in a C program.  Of course, there are then TOCTOU (time of check, time of use) problems.  But, nevertheless, it does exist.  So do quite a lot of other commands that are normally shell built-ins.

@Jabberwocky it's clear to me what a built-in is, I just wondered whether there is any way to pass back my will for a different working directory. So here's why I didn't find it yet: it can't be done

A child process cannot change the parent’s working directory in any normal way and should not do so. (It may be possible using debugging features, for example, by arranging for the child process to take debugging control of the parent and force it to execute chdir.)
Programs rely on the design of the programming environment. Changing the working directory of a process may be as disruptive to it as changing the values of its variables while it is running.

I completely agree, no objection. The question comes from the memory of some very old MS-DOS times file manager, that I feel had such a hack. Don't focus on "MS-DOS" and its features: I just wanted to know if that directory change was the product of a portable and well-known interface, that I simply didn't know

I just found a very cool tool that employs the only hack I figured so far, still being very portable. The file lister lf is very essential, can let you navigate through directories, and when launched by a script (in my case the one in etc/lfcd.cmd) can simply instruct the parent shell to change the working path. Yes, it does not change parent path as I asked if possible, but the result is the one I was looking for
